# Extract elements from JSON array and return them as concatenated string

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-10, postgresql-json

A PostgreSQL 10 table contains JSON data like (here an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/11342)):

```
[
    {
        "col": 7,
        "row": 12,
        "value": 3,
        "letter": "A"
    },
    {
        "col": 8,
        "row": 12,
        "value": 10,
        "letter": "B"
    },
    {
        "col": 9,
        "row": 12,
        "value": 1,
        "letter": "C"
    },
    {
        "col": 10,
        "row": 12,
        "value": 2,
        "letter": "D"
    }
]
```

How to extract only the "letter" values and concatenate them to a string like

```
ABCD
```

I suppose at the end I should use the [ARRAY_TO_STRING](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-array.html) function, but which [JSON function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-json.html) to use for extracting the "letter" values to an array?

**UPDATE:**

Got a tip at the very helpful PostgreSQL mailing list too:

```
SELECT string_agg(x->>'letter','') FROM json_array_elements(

'[{"col": 7, "row": 12, "value": 3, "letter": "A"}, {"col": 8, "row": 12, "value": 10, "letter": "B"}, {"col": 9, "row": 12, "value": 1, "letter": "C"}, {"col": 10, "row": 12, "value": 2, "letter": "D"}]'::json

) x;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) and [`string_agg():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
with my_table(json_data) as (
values(
'[
    {
        "col": 7,
        "row": 12,
        "value": 3,
        "letter": "A"
    },
    {
        "col": 8,
        "row": 12,
        "value": 10,
        "letter": "B"
    },
    {
        "col": 9,
        "row": 12,
        "value": 1,
        "letter": "C"
    },
    {
        "col": 10,
        "row": 12,
        "value": 2,
        "letter": "D"
    }
]'::jsonb)
)
select string_agg(value->>'letter', '')
from my_table
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(json_data)

 string_agg 
------------
 ABCD
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you... Why wouldn't the following work? `select string_agg( jsonb_array_elements( '[{"col": 7, "row": 12, "value": 3, "letter": "A"}, {"col": 8, "row": 12, "value": 10, "letter": "B"}]'::jsonb ) ->> 'letter', '' );`

Comment: It's a limitation of using a set returning function as an argument of an aggregate function. In cases like that use SRF in the `FROM` clause,